# How to open Bucket files using Google Cloud shell?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-shell

I already uploaded the files to `Google Cloud Platform Storage Bucket` and i wanted to access all the files using `Active Google Cloud Shell`? Should it be possible?

[image: sample pic]

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

https://cloud.google.com/shell/docs/examples#managing_cloud_storage_data

> You can also use the gsutil tool in Cloud Shell to manage Cloud
>   Storage resources. This includes creating and deleting buckets and
>   objects, copying and moving storage data, and managing bucket and
>   object ACLs. You can also use gsutil to transfer data in and out of
>   your Cloud Shell instance.

Comment: hi @Ilya Zakreuski thanks for the info, but i need to pull all the files from Bucket going to Cloud Shell.

Comment: @Smon: no probs, consider accepting the answer and marking your question as resolved. Cheers.

Comment: @Smon Did you find a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You open the object details in the bucket. It shows the URI for yoou to `gsutil cp gs://ju-chi-digits/sample_submission.csv sample.csv` from your google cloud shell

[image: screen of object details]